# CSS background-blend-mode no IE (Edge)

Tags: css, navegador-de-internet, internet-explorer, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

Estou fazendo um site, e para evitar hovers com outras imagens, utilizei o blend-mode no CSS. Mas segundo o [Can I Use?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode) os navegadores IE 11 e novo Edge não suportam.

Ai vem minha pergunta, em casos como esse, o que eu poderia fazer? Tentar alguma alternativa com opacity somente para estes navegadores? Ou simplesmente abandonar estes?

Obrigado pelas respostas! Mas ainda estou na dúvida...

Meu código é assim

```
figure.effect {
    background: #D68F27;
}

figure.effect img {
    opacity: 0.8;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s;
}

figure.effect:hover img {
    mix-blend-mode: soft-light;
    transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

É uma imagem com um fundo "#D68F27", e ela já tem opacity 0.8. Quando o hover é ativado entra o blend-mode.
No IE e Edge queria apenas que ficasse com opacity 0.3, ficaria mais fácil com o @suports? ou com JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como a implementação do blend-mode ainda vem sendo difundida no caso de navegadores como IE 11 e outros que não suportam seria bacana você já deixar o código funcionando caso esses algum dia viam a habilitar essa função (no caso da microsoft no edge agora).

Você pode conferir a compatibilidade dos navegadores com blend mode executando esse script:

```
var supportsMixBlendMode =
    window.getComputedStyle(document.body).mixBlendMode,
    supportsBackgroundBlendMode =
    window.getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundBlendMode;

console.log(supportsMixBlendMode);
console.log(supportsBackgroundBlendMode);
```

Se o valor retornado for normal o navegador possui compatibilidade porem se retornar
`undefined`, não tem jeito, nem `vendor prefixes` resolve!

Porém, acredito que você possa fazer algum outro efeito legal para esses navegadores, 
ou através de JS, verificando essas variáveis a cima e aplicando um estilo diferenciado
caso retorne `undefined`, ou também, você pode usar os famosos "hack" para CSS.

Aqui uma lista de alguns para o IE por exemplo:

http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/moving-ie-specific-css-into-media-blocks/

Acredito que de para fazer algo bem bacana talvez com zoom das imagens ou controle de
opacidade como você mesmo falou, ai vai da imaginação e do que combina melhor com o layout!

Espero ter ajudado, e por favor, 
se foi útil avalie a opinião e tentativa de resolução do problema,
abraço!

referências: 
- http://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/mixblendmode/
- http://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/

Você pode por exemplo fazer a verificação da seguinte maneira:

```
<script>
    var t = window.getComputedStyle(document.body).mixBlendMode,
        s = window.getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundBlendMode;

        if (undefined == (t&&s)) {
            //Aqui vai seu codigo ex.:
            //document.body.classList.add('n-blendMode');
            //document.body.style.color = "#000";
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apenas complementando a resposta anterior com a solução JS, existe também um recurso no CSS que pode facilitar seu trabalho. É o `@supports`. Através dele você verifica se determinada propriedade ou valor são suportados. Se houver suporte, você simplesmente sobrescreve as propriedades padrão usando a propriedade ou valor suportados. Por exemplo:

```css
b {
  background-color: red;
}

@supports ( background: linear-gradient(0deg,red,red) ) {
  b {
    background: linear-gradient( 0deg, rgb(65, 150, 44), rgb(26, 219, 73) );
  }
}
```

Nesse caso, o valor de background-color será "red" somente se o valor "linear-gradient(0deg,red,red)" não for suportado.

E caso o browser não reconheça o @supports (caso de versões anteriores do IE), o bloco @supports é ignorado, mantendo-se os valores padrão que você definiu anteriormente.

Agora, entre usar JS ou @supports, vai muito do recurso que você deseja utilizar. Na minha opinião, resolver somente no CSS seria o ideal. Mas infelizmente [nem todos os browsers implementam o @supports](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-featurequeries). Daí você pode cair no problema do browser implementar o recurso CSS que você quer mas não implementar o @supports. Neste caso o JS seria a solução pra você.

E para mais detalhes sobre isso e também sobre uso de CSS no Edge, acessar o link http://talkitbr.com/2015/08/19/prefixos-css-no-microsoft-edge/

Comment: Editei minha pergunta, vê o que achas...

Comment: Em relação ao suporte também é bem útil, porém ele funciona com sobrescrita,ou seja, onde o primeiro valor é red e se houver blendMode é mudado.. porem como você ira utilizar opacidade, você teria que também sobrescrever essa propriedade. Reaproveitando o exemplo acima, ficaria:

b {
  background-color: red;
opacity: 0.3;
}

@supports ( background: linear-gradient(0deg,red,red) ) {
  b {
    background: linear-gradient( 0deg, rgb(65, 150, 44), rgb(26, 219, 73) );
opacity: 0.8;
  }
}

Onde, caso suporte propriedade a opacidade seria 0.8 conforme você disse, e se não suportar seria 0.3;

Comment: Pois é, realmente resolver somente com CSS seria melhor, mas como o Safari ainda não implementa o @supports, estou achando melhor usar o JS.